# How to map an array base on other arrays without nested looping - JS/TS, ES6(7)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-2016

I have 2 arrays.

```js
const history = [
   { type: 'change', old: 1, new: 2 },
   { type: 'change', old: 3, new: 4 },
];

const contents = [
   { id: 1, info: 'infor1' },
   { id: 2, info: 'infor2' },
   { id: 3, info: 'infor3' },
   { id: 4, info: 'infor4' },
];
```

And the array in result

```js
const detailHistory = [
   { type: 'change', old: { id: 1, info: 'infor1' }, new: { id: 2, info: 'infor2' } },
   { type: 'change', old: { id: 3, info: 'infor3' }, new: { id: 4, info: 'infor4' } },
];
```

How can I create `detailHistory` without **nested looping** from `history` and `contents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a Map for the `contents`, so you can retrieve one of its objects by id. Once you have that, it comes down to mapping the `history` objects:

```js
const history = [
   { type: 'change', old: 1, new: 2 },
   { type: 'change', old: 3, new: 4 },
];

const contents = [
   { id: 1, info: 'infor1' },
   { id: 2, info: 'infor2' },
   { id: 3, info: 'infor3' },
   { id: 4, info: 'infor4' },
];

const contentsMap = new Map(contents.map(o => [o.id, o]));
const result = history.map(o => ({
    ...o,
    old: contentsMap.get(o.old),
    new: contentsMap.get(o.new)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Be aware that `old` and `new` will get object references to the **original** objects in `contents`... they are not copied. If this is undesired, then use a (shallow) copy at the moment you map them into the result:

```js
const history = [
   { type: 'change', old: 1, new: 2 },
   { type: 'change', old: 3, new: 4 },
];

const contents = [
   { id: 1, info: 'infor1' },
   { id: 2, info: 'infor2' },
   { id: 3, info: 'infor3' },
   { id: 4, info: 'infor4' },
];

const contentsMap = new Map(contents.map(o => [o.id, o]));
const result = history.map(o => ({
    ...o,
    old: {...contentsMap.get(o.old)},
    new: {...contentsMap.get(o.new)}
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution you can try:

```js
const history = [
  { type: "change", old: 1, new: 2 },
  { type: "change", old: 3, new: 4 }
];

const contents = [
  { id: 1, info: "infor1" },
  { id: 2, info: "infor2" },
  { id: 3, info: "infor3" },
  { id: 4, info: "infor4" }
];

let detailHistory = history.map((e, i) => {
  e.old = contents.find((element) => element.id === e.old);
  e.new = contents.find((element) => element.id === e.new);
  return e;
});
console.log(detailHistory);
```

Or you can use `Object.keys()` this way:

```js
const history = [
  { type: "change", old: 1, new: 2 },
  { type: "change", old: 3, new: 4 }
];

const contents = [
  { id: 1, info: "infor1" },
  { id: 2, info: "infor2" },
  { id: 3, info: "infor3" },
  { id: 4, info: "infor4" }
];

let detailHistory = history.map((e, i) => {
  Object.keys(e).map((key) => {
    e[key] = contents.find((element) => element.id === e[key])
      ? contents.find((element) => element.id === e[key])
      : e[key];
  });
  return e;
});
console.log(detailHistory);
```